# WPF application suddenly resized after a few weeks

Tags: asp.net, wpf, resize

I have a WPF application which looks like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-wl9oJvpFRsUE1QZ3ZwNjVaWTA/edit?usp=sharing

I installed it with a few of my customers and it was working fine for a few weeks, but after that I received complains that the application suddenly re-sized to looking like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-wl9oJvpFRscHpSMTBTMmVmZEU/edit?usp=sharing

The Window tag has the following properties:

```
<Window x:Class="Blabla.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        StateChanged="Window1_StateChanged" Icon="Ico.ico"
        Title="PRAMS Connect" Width="522" SizeToContent="Height" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
```

If they re-install the app their screen is back to the normal size.

Any idea what happened here?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a minimum height and width to your window;

```
<Window x:Class="Blabla.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StateChanged="Window1_StateChanged" Icon="Ico.ico"
    Title="PRAMS Connect" Width="522" SizeToContent="Height" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
    MinWidth="522" MinHeight="Whatever the height is...">
```